# How to calculate from string in Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making something like calculator, i am saving first value last value and also the operator (+, -, *, /) in variable, but its not giving me the desire result.

```
    var firstValue =$('#rt').text();
        var lastValue =$('#tr').text();
        var calculate = firstValue  r  lastValue;
        console.log(calculate);

        });
```

The output in console log showing something 6*4 but i want to show the calculation result which should be 24, any help please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: * will be r which is a variable and it can contain any symbol

Comment: what "r" denotes here?

Comment: eval(calculate) might help you

Comment: eval works but it is bad practice

Comment: You cannot use a string to directly perform the arithemetic operation. Use if-else/switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use switch cases for each operator.

```
var r = "*";
var firstValue =parseInt($('#rt').text(), 10);
var lastValue =parseInt($('#tr').text(), 10);
var calculate=0;
switch(r)
{
    case "+":
        calculate = firstValue + lastValue;
    break;
    case "-":
        calculate = firstValue - lastValue;
    break;
    case "*":
        calculate = firstValue * lastValue;
    break;
    case "/":
        calculate = lastValue!=0? firstValue / lastValue:"Can not divide by zero";
    break;
}

console.log(calculate);
```

Answer (score -2):

[`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) will do the job but its dangerous.
You should validate your input before using it.

Comment: but i have one more question ? is it possible to reset / empty all the variables one clicking on a specific button ?

Comment: @Code Spirit - As a developer you couldn't suggest the eval practice for other users. Nadeem - Don't use eval at any point as suggest by code spirit.